# Validate the unique string generated in the system

Tags: java, string, security, uniqueidentifier

I'm generating a unique id(generated by the frame work used are, so I should use only this ID and there is no API in the framework to check if this generated by the framework. Thanks RichieHH for pointing this) for each request in the web application and this can be presented back as a part of another request to the system. Now, I am storing these unique ID's generated in the database, and for every request the DB query is issued to check if this ID already exists(this is how the validation is done currently for the unique ID's). Now, if I have to validate the ID sent in the request has been generated by the application with out using the persistent storage, which approach should I be following?

My initial approacht is to generate the ID which adds to particular sum after hashing, but this can be identified after going through the patterns.

It will be great if some one can help me with an approach to solve this problem in a way it can validate the uniqueID generated with in the application. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're "checking" anyway, why not just use a unique ID generated by the underlying DB? If you dont wish to do this then it's an algorithm issue not really related to any specific language. Have you looked at the UUID classes? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: @RichieHH, thanks for getting back immediately. The unique ID is generated by the frame work we are using here.I have to use this but no other generator and that rules out using the UUID class. I missed to update it in the description, so will add it right away.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Use UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), which is pretty standard solution for this task. You don't need to validate UUID, you can assume that it is unique always.
2. You can use `ServerName+Timestamp+some extra`. It can be more advantageous for debug but less secure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I updated the reason for not using UUID, but currently doing some thing similar to the second approach having the unique ID generated by the framework and the time stamp. And the second approach has the same disadvantage as you described.

Comment: @user3174464 I didn't find any valid reason not to use UUID.

Comment: I will need to validate the unique ID sent back in another request, so I have to find a way if it is generated from the application since an unique ID can be generated outside the application. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.